Partial-pooled cluster estimates going away or beyond grand estimates in mixed models
I think I have a fairly good understanding about the main objectives and features of the partial pooling in mixed models. However, little details in the actual execution of the partial pooling are in conflict with the behavior I expect from the individual clusters. For example, in all the three demonstrations I will link below, various expressions are used to state that the cluster-specific intercept and slope estimates should move toward the corresponding grand estimates in the sample (staying still is also allowed). However, if you carefully follow some of the visualized motions of the cluster estimates from the no-pooled to partial-pooled versions, you can see how the cluster estimates can actually move away from the grand estimates along the individual axes. In some cases, the cluster estimates can also go beyond the grand estimates.
https://www.tjmahr.com/plotting-partial-pooling-in-mixed-effects-models/
https://towardsdatascience.com/when-mixed-effects-hierarchical-models-fail-pooling-and-uncertainty-77e667823ae8
https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-05-14-shrinkage-in-mixed-models/
At least the formulas defining the repositioning of the cluster intercepts alone (see the middle link above and this video lecture) show that the range of movement of individual clusters should be limited between the initial no-pooled positions and the grand estimates (to my best understanding, correct me if necessary). However, are the above contradicting observations related to the presence of both random intercepts and slopes in the same models, and their correlations? Haven't taken my ruler yet, but my gut feeling also says that although the cluster estimates can diverge along an individual axis, maybe the overall hypotenuses can become smaller during the partial pooling. Wrong: I actually took the ruler, and by measuring from the screen at least one of the overall distances increased due to the partial pooling (see the last listed website, the figure for df = create_data(sd_int = .25, sd_slope = 1), and one of the upper-right clusters).
If the observed behavior is not caused by an error, and I haven't misunderstood something, could the reasons be explained in some intuitive practical sense. Why the behavior is beneficial, although it does not seem to align with the main principles of the partial pooling. Why shouldn't all the cluster estimates move closer to the grand estimates along both the intercept and slope axes.
